# How to reformat multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have array like this with variable depth:

```
$array = [ // depth of array and number of values are variable
  'this' => [
       'a' => [
           'b' => 'some value'
       ],
       'c' => [
           'd' => 'some value'
       ],
  ],
  'that' => [
       'path' => [
            'to' => [
                'val' => 'some value'
            ],
       ]
  ]
];
```

and i need to have this:

```
$array['this.a.b'] => 'some value';
$array['this.c.d'] => 'some value';
$array['that.path.to.val'] => 'some value';
```

or this can be better:

```
$array[
 0 => [
   'key' => 'this.a.b',
   'val' => 'some value'
 ],
 1 => [
   'key' => 'this.c.d',
   'val' => 'some value'
 ],
 2 => [
   'key' => 'that.path.to.val',
   'val' => 'some value'
 ],
]
```

I need to take data from array and put them to easy form like:

```
<input name="this.a.b" value="some value">
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work well.

```
    private static function reformat($input, $k = '', &$keys = [])
{
    foreach($input as $key => $val) {
        $k .= '.' . $key;
        if (is_array($val)){
            static::reformat($val, $k, $keys);
        }else{
            $keys[$k] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Post your attempts. Post your expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found wanted solution and here it is:

```
function shorten($inputArray, $path = null, $separator = ".")
{

  $data = array();
  if (!is_null($path)) {
        $path = $path . $separator;
  }

  if (is_array($inputArray)) {
    foreach ($inputArray as $key => &$value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $data[$path . $key] = $value;
        } else {
            $data = array_merge($data, shorten($value, $path . $key, $separator));
        }
    }
  }

  return $data;
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [this.a.b] => some value
    [this.c.d] => some value
    [that.path.to.val] => some value
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/428092)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$array['this']['a']['b'];
$array['this']['c']['d'];
$array['this']['path']['to']['val'];
```

or

```
    function getVal($array, $key, $d='.') {
        $keyArray = explode($d, $key);
        $value = $array;
        foreach($keyArray as $k){
            if(isset($value[$k]))
                $value = $value[$k];
            else {
                $value = "";
                break;
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }


    echo getVal($array, 'this.path.to.val');
```

Comment: I need to get association path to val => val

Answer (score 0):

You can make your user define function as

```
$array = [
  'this' => [
       'a' => [
           'b' => 'some value'
       ],
       'c' => [
           'd' => 'some value'
       ],
  ],
  'that' => [
       'path' => [
            'to' => [
                'val' => 'some value'
            ],
       ]
  ]
];

function makesingledimesional($arr,$par = ''){
    $result = [];
    $final = [];
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value) && count($value)>0){
            $par .= "$key.";
            $result[$par] = makesingledimesional($value,$par);
        }else{
            $result[$par.$key] = $value;
        }

    }
    array_walk_recursive($result,function($v,$k)use(&$final){$final[$k] = $v;});
    return $final;
}

print_r(makesingledimesional($array));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [this.a.b] => some value
    [this.a.c.d] => some value
    [this.that.path.to.val] => some value
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/427479)

Comment: That is bad because second key should be only this.c.d and next one only that.path.to.val. My function did the same problem.